# Whats the symmetric, anti-symmetric and non-symmetric part of the direct product of irreducible representations?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, symmetry, group-theory

I am trying to understand how to see if a vibrational mode is Jahn-Teller active or not. According to the [group theoretical description of the Jahn-Teller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect&section=9#Symmetry_of_JT_systems_and_categorisation_using_group_theory) one needs to check if the symmetric part of the direct product the irreducible representation (=irrep) of the electronic state with itself contains the irrep of the distortional mode in its *symmetric part*. And this is where I have trouble to understand. I can understand that one can decompose tensors (tensor products) into a symmetric and an anti-symmetric part, but I fail to understand how to apply that to the the direct product of two irreps, as they are in most cases one-dimensional. Can someone explain to me what exactly means "symmetric, anti-symmetric and non-symmetric part" in this context and how to see that in specific cases?

Comment: When they are one-dimensional, there is nothing to decompose.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: OK, so lets take the example E$_g$ in D$_{4h}$.

Comment: You should probably find some 'direct product' tables to speed up multiplying symmetry species. The symmetric stretch, say in CO2, is when CO bonds both stretch in phase, anti-symmetric when one stretches as the other compresses, $\pi/2$ out of phase. Anti-symmetric is somewhat subjective in a complex molecule and so this and anything else can be called asymmetric.  (Asymmetric means 'no symmetry' which in not the case as all symmetry species are determined by the point group.)

Comment: In $D_{4h}$ product of E with anything but E is E, and $E \times E \to A_1+[A_2]+B_1+B_2$ where [] mean anti-symmetrized product  of a degenerate representation with itself.

Comment: My tables tell me: $\mathrm{E_g}\otimes\mathrm{E_g}=\mathrm{A_{1g}}\oplus\mathrm{A_{2g}}\oplus\mathrm{B_{1g}}\oplus\mathrm{B_{2g}}$, while they charcterize $\mathrm{A_{2g}}$ as being "antisymmetric with respect to particle permutation". So whats then symmetric, non-symmetric and whats asymmetric. I am also specifically interested in the "anti-symmetric" part since I want to analyze the system also relativistically (in double group $D_{4h}^*$)

Comment: @porphyrin: Yes, and now I want to know, whats the "symmetric part" and whats the "anti-symmetric" part and whats the "non-symmetric" part, how does it relate to this peculiar "antisymmetrized product", how does it relate to the (possibly inversion-anti) symmetry of the stretch you mention and how this is defined exactly? I do also not see how a non-symmetric part can be left over, since decompostion into symmetric and anti-symmetric part of a tensor should leave no rest.

Comment: @porphyrin: So what you describe in your CO$_2$ example seems to mean totally symmetric and not totally symmetric, like A$_1$, or similar, but that does not make sense in this context.

Comment: There seems to be a description of what you want, re symmetrized and anti - symmetrized direct products in section 5.14 of the 3rd edition of Atkins & Friedman 'Molecular Quantum Mechanics' publ OUP.

Comment: @porphyrin: In 5.36 there, shouldn't it rather be $\chi^+(R^2)$, instead of  $\chi^+(R)$?

Comment: 5.36 is some other equation in my copy. In general the symmetric $\chi^+$ and antisymmetric $\chi^-$ components of a direct product have characters given by the formula character $\chi^+=([\chi(R)]^2+\chi(R^2))/2$ and $\chi^-=([\chi(R)]^2-\chi(R^2))/2$ where $\chi(R)$ is the character for operation $R$ and $\chi(R^2)$ the character for the square of the operation.

Comment: @porphyrin: So what would be the "direct product" part here, then?

Comment: In  $D_{4h}$ in the product $E\times E$ using $\chi^+$ should produce the $[A_2]$ term given above.

Comment: Sure, but where is it in the equation?

Comment: I don't think that I can help anymore. To see how it works you will have to work out the direct product by multiplying the characters and then form the irreps from that result.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric and antisymmetric part of the direct product here refers to the fact that certain irreducible representations in the direct product are symmetric while others are antisymmetric (w.r.t some operations like $\sigma_v$, $C'_2$). So, for instance, when we write:

$$\Pi \times \Pi = \Sigma^+ + [\Sigma^-] + \Delta$$

the $[ \ ]$ simply means that the irreducible representation $\Sigma^-$ is the antisymmetric part of the direct product. It doesn't mean that you are somehow decomposing $\Sigma^-$ into a symmetric and antisymmetric part, and then selecting the antisymmetric one. This won't be possible since $\Sigma^-$ is a one-dimensional representation.

Comment: So what are the "defining" group elements then, that have to be checked, is that an arbitrary definition? One might suppose something like the highest order generator element....